# Visual Studio puts all connection strings on one line

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, web-config

Every time I add a new entity and connection string, Visual Studio 2012 stores all of my connection strings on one line.

Old format:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!--comment describing this string -->
    <add name="connString" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <!--comment describing this string2 -->
    <add name="connString2" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

New format:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!--comment describing this string --><!--comment describing this string2 --><add name="connString" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />add name="connString2" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

How do I prevent it from doing this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in my copy of Visual Studio 2012 tinkering with all the Visual Studio formatting settings. It's really odd that the arrangement of comments isn't preserved either. Are you running any plugins or addons? Maybe see if the issue presents itself when you run Visual Studio in [safe mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx)?